# Avoid images being stripped in email replies

Tags: html, image, outlook, signature

I had a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10732829/html-email-signature-returning-png-file-on-outlook-reply) which kind of helped but didn't explain how to fix the issue.

I have created a signature in word, copied it to outlook which embeds fine. It works well, except for some replies where the images are stripped and the code remains.

Does anyone have any ideas why this happens? Is there any way to stop this from happening?

[image]

Comment: Are you saying this happens when someone replies to your email?

Answer (score 7):

Replying to an email in a lot of email clients, the images, attachments, etc. are removed/replaced. Hence the issue is not up to you but to the person replying to your mail, to avoid unnecessary large emails (which is a good thing I suppose), since its assumed you still have a copy of the original message anyway.

What you could try to do is upload the images to a server and link them from there into your message using html `<img>` tags like

```
<img src="yourServer/image011.png" alt="image011.png" />
```

and encode the section as `html`.

In this way, the image is not directly a part of your email anymore and is therefore unlikely to be replaced by the responders client.

A downside of this is, a lot of clients do not directly download referenced files anymore for privacy and security reasons. The responder then would have to agree to download the images.

Comment: The reason I wanted to embed the images is so the user doesn't have to download them. its a bit of a pain.

Comment: The user has to download them no matter what. Directly with the email or with another request. Using another server for the image, the client might even cache it, making it even more efficient.